# Push notification in adobe air (android and ios) with urbanairship/parse

Tags: air, push-notification, adobe

I am looking for a solution or a guideline for one that will enable me to register to one of the big services that enable push notification. 
 I know that it will be easier in IOS http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios-push-notifications.html 
 I have problem with it android even though I successfully send a push notification to android. but without registration like explained Heading here.
http://afterisk.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/the-only-free-and-fully-functional-android-gcm-native-extension-for-adobe-air/
Could someone direct me to a solution
Thanks

Comment: Why won't you use the native extension?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelIV I did try to use write one but am using starling but I have to create a service to use those sdk. anyway if you seen some guideline of someone how done that I will be happy to follow his steps